# Combine pi-hole and nxfilter on 1 raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, pihole

Given I have a raspberry pi 4 with Raspbian Buster, I would like to combine pi-hole  (for adblocking) and nxfilter (for parental controls).

I could specify nxfilter as the upstream dns server for pi-hole or vice versa.

Problem is, both services use port 53 and I cannot see an option in either to change their port.
For nxfilter however, I could change the listen-ip address, which in turn leads me to believe that if I can assign an additional ip address to the raspberry, I could have nxfilter listen on the additional ip only, resolving the conflict regarding port 53.

Right now the raspberry receives a dynamic address from the dhcp server (fixed assigned ip however).

So the question is: how do I assign an additional static ip address to the raspberry?

Comment: Hi ! I am interesting in building same kind of setup .. any update on this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might get some information [in this article that got both installed with docker](https://community.nethserver.org/t/how-to-install-nxfilter-and-pihole-with-docker/14976)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Link-only comments are discouraged. Please edit your answer to include the details of why that link answers the question.

Comment: I mean, the link name seem obvious to me ... article on how to have both nxfilter and pi-hole both installed at the same time using docker ...